# C# : Projection of a dictionary<int, IList<string>> to a flat list of class using LINQ

Tags: c#, projection

Having trouble trying to project the data in a `dictionary <int, IList<string>>` to a class that has the structure of

```
public class MyClass {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Info {get; set;}
}

private Dictionary<int, IList<string>> myData;
```

Now myData is an Id which has a list of pieces of info.  I need to get it into a List

so that that MyClass list will have values like:

```
Id = 1, Info = "line 1"
Id = 1, Info = "line 2"
Id = 1, Info = "line 3"
Id = 2, Info = "something else"
Id = 2, Info = "another thing"
```

haven't gotten close to projecting this.  Figure to use SelectMany, but haven't gotten anything to match this.

Comment: let me know how to improve this... find it quite clear. no need to negate the question.

Comment: `myData.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => new MyClass { Id = kvp.Key, Info = v }));`

Comment: Your question is very broad, lacking any evidence that you made any effort to try anything at all, never mind a good [mcve] showing clearly what _specifically_ you're having trouble with. It was so vague, I originally misunderstood what you were even trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I really meant to ask for a LINQ solution.  going to check juharr solution as soon as i can.

Comment: @GrantWinney Ur right.. i'm silly that i got stuck on a LINQ solution, but that is what i had in mind.  i forgot the explicitly say that, other than stating i 'figured' to use SelectMany in the stated issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho sorry i wanted a linq solution and my attempts were so bad, i didn't want to post it.

Comment: @juharr .. Tx.. Exactly what i was looking for... If you post it as an answer, i'll give you credit!  Was trying to do it this way from the start, but couldn't figure that out.

Comment: @user1161137 Would have answered it but the question was closed at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, using `System.Linq`:

```
List<MyClass> classList = myData.Keys
    .SelectMany(key => myData[key], (key, s) => new MyClass {Id = key, Info = s})
    .ToList();
```

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Start with a dictionary of Ids and a List<string> of Infos
    var myData = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
    {
        {1, new List<string> {"line 1", "line 2", "line 3" } },
        {2, new List<string> {"something else", "another thing" } },
    };

    // Convert it into a list of MyClass objects
    var itemList = myData.Keys
        .SelectMany(key => myData[key], (key, s) => new MyClass { Id = key, Info = s })
        .ToList();

    // Output each MyClass object to the Console window
    Console.WriteLine("The list of MyClass contains the following objects:");
    foreach(var item in itemList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyClass: Id = {item.Id}, Info = {item.Info}");
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much Rufus.  This is what i was looking for... although i like juharr solution a bit better.. easier to write imo... myData.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => new MyClass { Id = kvp.Key, Info = v }));   But i'll mark yours as the answer since he didn't 'answer' the question and your solution is good too!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
List<MyClass> Project(Dictionary<int, IList<string>> data)
{
    List<MyClass> result = new List<MyClass>();
    foreach (int key in data.Keys)
        foreach (string s in data[key])
            result.Add(new MyClass { Id = key, Info = s });
    return result;
}
```

The idea is to iterate over every int, and within that to iterate over every string associated with that int. And add every one of those combinations (of int and string) to the result.